# bootstrap carousel not loading image realative link wrong?

Tags: php, image, twitter-bootstrap

So i was trying to use the bootstrap Carousel, but it doesnt loade the picture. If i add a link from a picture on google then it does show it. Is there something i'm doing wrong with the relative paths ?

[image: code]
[image: path]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use`img/img1.jpg`, not `img\img1.jpg`.

Comment: And what happens when you go to `http://localhost/img/img1.jpg` in the browser (assuming localhost)?

Comment: he doesnt find it since i'm using a frontcontroller, but when i go to its full path, then he does.

Comment: and ofc i forgot to look in my error_log wich say's: "[20-Jan-2014 19:46:28 Europe/Brussels] File not found: application/controller/ImgController.php" but how can i solve this ?

Comment: Fix your config to not pass valid file URLs to the front controller.